# Can I select a field from data type?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sqldatatypes

Can I select a field/column from data type?

Postgres 7.4 (yep we are upgrading)

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl_name
WHERE tbl_name.column = 'timestamp with time zone'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That requires metadata.

```
select column_name
from information_schema.columns
where table_schema='your_schema'
and table_name='tbl_name'
and data_type='timestamp without time zone'
order by ordinal_position;
```

ETA:  If you want the actual data from the table with column names matching the list above, you could probably set up a user-defined function that would grab those column names, put them in a comma-delimited list, and parse the query from tbl_name appropriately (of course, this is a lot easier if you're working in a scripting language slightly outside of the database).

Comment: The "order by" statement isn't necessary, but it does retrieve the column names in the order in which they normally appear (by default) in the table.

Comment: Error: column "your_schema" does not exist

Comment: Thanks that did it. Also if anyone else runs into this some of the older tables names use Upper Case, which you're to use double quotes instead of single quotes like this: table_name="Tbl_Name". This is NOT the case, use single quotes as well even if you have camel case names like this: table_name='Tbl_Name'.

Answer (score 1):

I had to do that recently. To ease things I defined two views :

```
CREATE  VIEW view_table_columns AS 
 SELECT n.nspname AS schema, cl.relname AS table_name, 
  a.attname AS column_name, ty.typname AS data_type, 
  a.attnotnull AS nnull, 
  a.atthasdef AS hasdef, 
  descr.description AS descr, cl.oid AS tableoid, a.attnum AS colnum
   FROM pg_attribute a
   JOIN pg_class cl ON a.attrelid = cl.oid AND cl.relkind = 'r'::"char"
   JOIN pg_namespace n ON n.oid = cl.relnamespace
   JOIN pg_type ty ON ty.oid = a.atttypid
   LEFT JOIN pg_description descr 
       ON descr.objoid = cl.oid AND descr.objsubid = a.attnum
   WHERE a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped 
       AND n.nspname !~~ 'pg_%'::text 
       AND n.nspname <> 'information_schema'::name;

COMMENT ON VIEW view_table_columns IS 'Lista all fields of all tables';


CREATE VIEW view_table_columns2 AS 
 SELECT view_table_columns.*, 
 ( SELECT count(*) AS count
      FROM pg_index
      WHERE pg_index.indrelid = pg_index.tableoid AND 
  (view_table_columns.colnum = ANY   (pg_index.indkey::smallint[]))) AS indexes
   FROM view_table_columns;

COMMENT ON VIEW view_table_columns2 IS 'Adds to view_table_columns info about indexed fields';
```

That includes, for every field in your tables the following info:

- schema name
- table name
- column name
- data_type name
- is nullable?
- has default value?
- description (comment)
- tableoid    (handy if you need to get more data from catalog)
- column number  (idem)
- indexes    (in second view - number of indexes that refer to this column)